# Are there reasons for the discrepancies in absolute temp units - Kelvin vs. kelvins vs. degrees Kelvin?

Tags: temperature, si-units, conventions

Before 1968, the units for absolute temperature were described as "degrees Kelvin" or "degrees absolute."  After that, the SI system got rid of the idea of "degree" for absolute temperature, so the new unit should apparently be expressed as a "kelvin" (with lowercase k) and abbreviated simply "K" (without the degree sign).  Also, [official SI conventions](http://www.bipm.org/utils/common/pdf/si_brochure_8_fr.pdf) suggest that not only should the unit name be lowercase, but it should be pluralized as other units would be: "Il en résulte que la température thermodynamique du point triple de l’eau est égale à 273,16 kelvins exactement, Ttpw = 273,16 K."  Or, [in English](http://www.bipm.org/en/si/base_units/kelvin.html): "It follows that the thermodynamic temperature of the triple point of water is exactly 273.16 kelvins, Ttpw = 273.16 K."

Despite the official SI usage, however, it seems that there are still a variety of conventions in use.  Many of the questions on this forum, for example, use Kelvin (with a capital) instead of kelvin in referencing the unit.  Also, it appears that the plural usage is somewhat mixed in the physics literature: something like "200 kelvins" occurs, but more rarely than "200 kelvin" or even "200 Kelvin."  The [NIST guidelines](http://physics.nist.gov/Pubs/SP811/sec09.html) do not list the kelvin as an exception to the normal pluralization rules: "the following plurals are irregular: Singular — lux, hertz, siemens; Plural — lux, hertz, siemens."  On the other hand [CERN's writing guidelines](http://writing-guidelines.web.cern.ch/entries/kelvin) suggest that there is an exception: "And note that it is always kelvin, even when plural (not kelvins or degrees kelvin)."

Given all of this, here is my question: Is the SI standard actually to pluralize kelvins, as would be suggested from the quotations from the official SI guides above?  Is this officially stated anywhere in some standards organization's guidelines?  Or, is there some rationale given somewhere for the continued use of plural "kelvin" (as in the CERN guidelines) or even "Kelvin" (with an apparently anomalous capital)?

Or, is it -- as I suspect -- just a failure to treat the kelvin as an actual SI unit, despite the redefinition from "degrees Kelvin" to "kelvins" that happened decades ago?  (Perhaps we just dropped the "degree" but effectively still treat it the same way as Celsius or Fahrenheit?)

**EDIT:** Just to be clear -- I did NOT intend for this to be only a question about linguistic convention.  The SI redefinition of the absolute temperature scale and units was apparently meant to refine or change some physical conception about temperature.  Resistance to this change may indicate some other elements about the underlying physics (perhaps including the fact that temperature is an intensive property, as suggested in one answer below).  While I'd certainly be interested in other official standards and usage recommendations, I also wanted to know if there were other PHYSICAL rationales for the inconsistent units.

Comment: My personal tendency is to capitalize people's names, so it is natural to capitalize Kelvin.  I don't think too many people care one way or another.

Comment: You've cited three standards already - do you want us to cite more standards? Or do you just want input from actual working scientists on what is acceptable?

Comment: There are TONS of non-standard units in use.  In my line of work, I'm stuck with people using 'nm' for Nautical Miles :-( .  As to Kelvins: removal of "degrees" saves us two syllables or an annoying "raised tiny 'o' " every time we use the unit.

Comment: For example, as an American-English speaking astrophysicist, I can tell you that spelled-out units are usually lowercase; "kelvin" is treated as a mass noun; "degrees" is only used *in place of* "kelvin;" there are optional exceptions in phrases like "temperature in degrees Kelvin" or "temperature in kelvins;" and in practice most of this is moot because when attached to numbers one always uses e.g. "5 K." Of course, other fields and other countries can be very different. In particular, note that French is not Germanic, and tends to eschew capitalization more as a result.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about naming conventions for units and not physics.

Comment: @ChrisWhite - The SI standards guide I cited only gives an example of usage, but it doesn't clarify what the usage is supposed to be.  The NIST guidelines actually don't have anything on topic; my argument there is only from absence.  So I've actually only found ONE clear reference of a style guide making a clear recommendation (CERN), and that appears to disagree with the other two.  I've heard arguments about this question more than once, so I'm trying to figure out whether there are other sources that clarify the matter.

Comment: @KyleKanos - One of the rationales I've heard for changing "degrees Kelvin" to "kelvins" in the 1960s was because supposedly there was a fundamental physical difference in the conception of the unit, given the special nature of absolute zero.  Arguably, then, kelvins were not "degrees" of hot or cold, as Celsius or Fahrenheit might be.  If the usage has not changed to reflect these SI recommendations, perhaps it does affect the way we present and talk about the nature of temperature and its "degrees."  (Hence, various questions here about WHY the kelvin scale is the way it is, etc.)

Comment: You are still arguing over definitions of words, not asking a question about physics.

Comment: @KyleKanos - But the rationale for changing the name of the unit was to reflect some idea about physics; if people refuse that change, does that suggest a different interpretation of the physics?  (Already below someone has suggested it may have to do with ideas about intensive vs. extensive properties, and that sounds like part of an explanation.)  If this is off-topic, where can I ask the question?  The "English language and usage" forum is unlikely to have experts to weigh in on a question like this, and it's actually a cross-language problem of scientific nomenclature.

Comment: What counts is that it is *not* on topic here, so I'm not too concerned about where you can get an answer to a virtually meaningless question.

Comment: @KyleKanos - I'm not going to get into a debate in comments.  I was welcoming your assistance, but instead I get told my question is "virtually meaningless."  Obviously the SI committee who decided to make changes to unit names didn't think it was "meaningless" or they wouldn't have bothered.  They obviously thought they were doing something.  I apologize if my question offends you; I just thought it was similar to many other questions here which have asked about the nature of units and their conventional use.

Comment: Your question didn't offend me, your insistence that it is on topic is a tad annoying. I see the question as meaningless because if someone didn't know what you mean using any of the three ways, you have bigger problems than verbiage.

Answer (score 4):

The NIST style guide is pretty good — that's a place where people really care about getting details right.

I use lower-case names for spelled-out units, even when named for famous people or having uppercase abbreviations (N -> newton, J -> joule, L -> liter (unless you count $\ell$ for liter), K -> kelvin).  I think that "degrees kelvin" is entirely by analogy with "degrees Celsius" and "degrees Fahrenheit" (the latter two of which I think I have always seen capitalized).

I *don't* pluralize "kelvin" when talking about temperatures: I talk about temperatures like "two hundred fifty millikelvin," or "four kelvin" for the boiling point of helium, or "three hundred kelvin" for room temperature. This is not consistent with the way that I would discuss a length unit, or a mass unit.

I think that this may be because temperature is an [intensive variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intensive_variable).  If I have a thing that weighs a kilogram, and another thing that weighs four kilograms, and I put them together, I know that I have five kilograms worth of stuff. But if I have some stuff at one kelvin, and some other stuff at four kelvins, and I mix them together, I don't get some stuff at five kelvins.  I know this, and so I don't think of "a kelvin" as a lump of temperature that I can carry around and add or subtract to things.

I feel the same way about the hertz: I have no desire to say "sixty hertzes." Combining an oscillator at 60 Hz and an oscillator at 10 Hz gives me something much more complicated than an oscillator at 70 Hz. I notice that "hertz" is listed as one of your three exceptions, though.

If that's really my thought process I would make the same decision about the pascal (for pressure) and the poise (for viscosity); I can't think off the top of my head of another intensive quantity with a named unit. I *think* that if you asked me I would tell you that air pressure at sea level is "ten to the five pascal," but I'm focusing too hard on it and I'm honestly not sure.

---

In response to a comment: I definitely *do* say things like "two atmospheres of pressure," but never "two bars" or "one thousand torrs." It could well be that dealing with kelvins one by one is so rare that I don't think of them as being countable. Interesting.

Comment: Thanks -- I think the intensive variable thing is important, and I hadn't quite thought of it in those terms.  To my mind, for example, gauss is usually same in singular and plural, but tesla can sometimes go either way.  Pressure seems to be a bit of a mixed bag too: bar and torr are definitely singular and plural, atmosphere sometimes (to my ear), but I would tend to pluralize pascals.  But this sounds like it may explain some of the inconsistency with kelvin/s.

Comment: But "hertz" is likely counted as an irregular plural for phonetic reasons.  Am three of them end with a consonant cluster ending with an /s/ or /z/ sound. Nobody ever had a problem with the plural of _cycle per second_ being _cycles per second._